# Download a folder directly from the server

Tags: php, html, server, download, directory

I have a folder of 3.9GB which I need to send to my another computer using html. but if I just copy and paste it in my /var/www/html and start the apache service it shows the folder in the web page, but clicking the folder makes the folder to open and then the sub-folders opens on clicking. I want the whole folder to be downloaded at one click.
`<a href="foldername" download>Link text</a>`
on clicking this link the download.html file is downloaded.

Comment: Downloading folder from server is not possible directly . You can zip the folder using php and you can make its as downloadable

Comment: Memory stick comes to mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**3.9GB** is quite big. Directly downloading a folder is not possible. Zip/tar and downloading is very slow. Why not use [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync)?

`rsync` can compress and download the whole directory. What's more important, it can continue the download progress if broken or paused.